# Does this Smartcontract work?

Tags: contract-deployment

I have a contract, it only shows data on etherscan only "0x". I want to ask if it still works or not? and can interact with that contract? .
contract is only 1 tx is to create smart contract

[image]

Comment: Please test ur contract on some test network first and not on the main chain

Answer (score 0):

No it does not work. Your contract is empty. A real contract would have a lot of data in the field shown in your screenshot.